# How to unwrap parent using beautiful soup4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Given an html page source such as:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p><nobr><a href="...">Some link text</a></nobr><p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And without explicitly knowing what tags are wrapping the `<a>` element (could be anything, not just nobr). How can I create a loop that keeps unwrapping the parent of a given `<a>` tag until its parent is a paragraph?

Something like:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

page = "https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/rebuilding-iraq/"
link="http://www.elca.org/ScriptLib/OS/Congregations/cdsDetail.asp?congrno=12962"

r = http.request('get', page)
body = r.data
soup = bs(body, 'lxml')
a = soup.find('a', href=link)

while True:
    if a.parent.name == "p":
        break
    else:
        a.parent.name.unwrap() #doesnt work as name is string
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find_parents` for given child tag.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = "https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/rebuilding-iraq/"
link="http://www.elca.org/ScriptLib/OS/Congregations/cdsDetail.asp?congrno=12962"

r = requests.get(page)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
a = soup.find('a', href=link)

for tag in a.find_parents('p'):
    print(tag)
```

### Output:

```
<p><font class="copyright_text_color" color="" face=""><b>Origins:</b></font>   This item is “true” in the sense that Eric Rydbom is indeed an engineer stationed in Iraq with the Army’s <nobr>4th Infantry</nobr> Division, and he sends monthly <nobr>e-mail</nobr> dispatches such as the one quoted above to fellow members of his congregation at the <nobr><a href="http://www.elca.org/ScriptLib/OS/Congregations/cdsDetail.asp?congrno=12962" target="_blank">First Lutheran</a></nobr> Church of Richmond Beach in Shorline, Washington.  This piece was one of those messages, forwarded to the church’s prayer chain and thence to the larger world via the Internet.</p>
```

---

If you want to get the text just use.

```
for tag in a.find_parents('p'):
    print(tag.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way with bs4 4.7.1. is to use :has and an attribute = value selector. No need for looping.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = "https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/rebuilding-iraq/"
link="http://www.elca.org/ScriptLib/OS/Congregations/cdsDetail.asp?congrno=12962"
r = requests.get(page)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('p:has([href="' + link + '"])'))
```